# String join with newline in an array in Coffeescript/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, coffeescript, underscore.js, jsx

I'm currently using the Instagram API to retrieve a user post's caption as well as their hashtags. I'm mapping each post but I'm having trouble joining the array with newline; also, I want to add a hashtag symbol before each hashtag. I know this sounds confusing, but I'll demonstrate with code snippet and screenshot:

[image]

This is the photo object that I have access to. If you look under "tags", there are four hashtags that I want to display. All four of them are displaying, but in the same line, and only the beginning line gets the hashtag.

```
eachPost: (post) ->
  return (
    <tr>
      <td>#{post.tags.join("\r\n")}</td>
    </tr>
  )

render: () ->
  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>Hashtags</th>
        </tr>
        {_.chain(@state.posts.data).map(@eachPost).value()}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  )
```

This is what's showing up. The left column is Caption, and right column is Hashtags:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This should fix the problem that only the first element gets the hashtag:

```
eachPost: (post) ->
  return (
    <tr>
      <td>"##{post.tags.join("\r\n#")}"</td>
    </tr>
  )
```